# Error in installing Nuget Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors in Web API2 application - Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, nuget-package

I am trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package to impliment CORS in my Web API application.I am using below command to install package:

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

But it's giving me following Error:

> Install-Package : Unable to load the service index for source >https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.Install>PackageCommand

I am using visual studio 2015 and .net framework 4.5.1 in my project.
When I run **Get-Package -ListAvailable** in package manager console it shows:

> No packages found in the current package source.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether the nuget.org is chosen or not as the package source in package Console. If not choose the nuget.org as the package source, you must choose nuget.org as the package console. Also make sure that the nuget target is **"https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"**.(in Visual Studio 2019- version 16.9.2)
To change the package source go to Tools>>NuGet Package Manager>> Package Manager Settings>> Nuget Package Manager >>Package Source>> .